# Airplane mode getting stuck on after suspend in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management

Although [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214760/airplane-mode-gets-turned-on-and-stuck-after-sleep-mode) asks about the same problem, none of the proposed solutions work on my HP Pavilion 15 laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.

The suggestion from "nobody" on the earlier question, which is to type

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.rfkill active false
```

results in the error `No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.rfkill”` and I can't find any other .rfkill entries in gsettings when I type

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep rfkill
```

the output is

```
    org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys rfkill ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys rfkill-bluetooth ['']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys rfkill-bluetooth-static ['XF86Bluetooth']
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys rfkill-static ['XF86WLAN', 'XF86UWB', 'XF86RFKill']
```

Creating the systemd unit file in `/etc/systemd/system` as suggested by Gryu and MysticAxolotl doesn't produce any errors but also doesn't solve the problem which is:

When Ubuntu is suspended under the Power Off/Logout > Suspend Gnome menu item, and then restarted either by pressing the laptop power switch or Esc key, Airplane mode is turned on and cannot be switched off, either via the Fn + F12 key combination nor via the setting menu (which reports that wifi is hardware disabled).

Any new suggestions?